# For my App Store distribution setup, what security items should I back up?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, mac-app-store

I've submitted my first app to Apple for the App Store (huzzah!).  In the process, I had to set up a bunch of security and authentication pieces that I didn't understand well at all (and the Apple documentation is confusing and even self-contradictory in places, oi).  Provisioning profiles, security certificates, account IDs, ... lions, tigers, bears, oh my!

I should keep an extra copy of all the security/authentication-related items, because they're extra important.  If all my Macs die, I can recreate all the source code I wrote last week, but it'd be impossible to recreate a lost security certificate.

What all files/etc are created and stored on my Mac, as part of App Store distribution, which I should back up, and how do I do that?  That is, besides the source code to my project (which is in a remote Git repo), if all my Macs simultaneously caught fire right now, what else would I need in order to submit a new build to Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there's not a lot you couldn't recreate to get you the ability to submit a new version of your app.  If you want to be able to use the same certificates, as well as be able to generate future certificates for the same private key, I would back up the private keys and the .csr (cert signing request) files you used to generate certificates in the Apple developer center.  Technically, you can generate a new CSR using the private key, but to save yourself some trouble, I would backup both.

The private key can be exported from the Keychain Access app on your Mac.  The csr file should be somewhere on your computer when you followed Apple's steps to generate certificates.

Note that you should make sure your private key is protected, because with it, someone else could build an app that would appear signed by you and submit it to Apple (your iTunes Connect credentials would also need to be compromised.

With those two files, you would be fine, as you can download the certificate and provisioning profiles from the Apple developer site.

However, in the worst case scenario, if you lost everything, you could simply follow the same process to generate a new private key, and csr, and create a new certificate and provisioning profile to use after the disaster.